# JMH testing produces tons of "interrupt" messages

Tags: java, microbenchmark, jmh

I've been running some JMH microbenchmarks lately and I started randomly seeing this happen to some of my test runs:

```
> # Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:20:00
> # Fork: 1 of 5
> # Warmup Iteration   1: (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*)
> (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*)
```

Initially the "`(*interrupt*)` messages don't appear, but after some time they come out in a giant stream. I've had a lot of compatibility issues and tried compiling my code under Java 8, 11, and 14, and sometimes I have to run my jar directly instead of within IntelliJ, but sometimes it works fine.

Comment: I found basically the same question asked elsewhere, answered by Aleksey Shipïlev, the JMH author. Is that an answer for you, too?

Comment: Yes. For some reason I wasn't able to find that using Google, and it didn't show up when I was creating this question either.